# Converting Javascript Alert Into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

```
<script> $.getJSON("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson", function(json) 
      {console.log(json);  var newString = JSON.stringify(json, null, 0)var obj = JSON.parse(newString);alert(obj.features.length) })</script>
```

A helpful wrote some code which brought up an alert box on my website www.livehazards.com.

How do I convert this line of code into html so I can display that same sentence in my sidebar

Thanks in advance

```
 alert("There have been  " + obj.features.length + "  Earthquakes in the last month");
```

Comment: You should learn some DOM manipulation, rather than asking questions on SO every step of the way. It is quite easy to select an element in DOM, and set its `innerText`.

Comment: Hey thanks, I did look up DOM manipulation but couldn't get my mind around it. I would like just help with this bit and then i will figure what to do.  Please could you write the code needed?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery (since it looks like you're using jQuery there):

```
$("#elementID").text("There have been " + obj.features.length + " Earthquakes in the last month");
```

Where elementID is the ID of the element you want the text inside of.

Comment: Hey thanks but I don't want text inside element. I just to display that alert javascript as html within my sidebar

Comment: I don't quite understand. You want the word "alert" and all that to show as plain text somewhere you mean?

Comment: No. At the moment I have an alert popup box when you open my website, see www.livehazards.com, this shows the count of how many earthquakes there have been in the last month. I want to copy the sentence which is in the alert box to normal html text. The number of earthquakes has been imported from a GeoJson file and updates every few minutes.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that's not exactly what my answer is

Comment: Hey thanks, ok, but what do I put in $("#elementID")?. I can't figure out whether it would be.....# json or #newString or #obj.features.length)?

Comment: '#' represents what would be an "id" so if you have a tag with id="x" on it, then you'd use "#x". You can add an id to the element you want that sentence to be inside of. Something like `<div id="earthquakes"></div>` and `$("#earthquakes")`

Comment: Hey thanks I tried that and its not working. I did  <div id="earthquakecount"></div> and put $("#earthquakecount") ...but nothing shows